# Reverting Vissicitude effects with Temporis

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages

Well, I have a player whose vampire has the Flaw "Flesh of the Corpse". The description in the book is something like this:

"Your flesh does not fully regenerate itself once it is damaged. While you are able to heal yourself to the point of regaining full functionality, your skin still retains the cuts, tears, bullet holes, etc., which you have incurred. Depending on the nature of the damage, this Flaw will make social dealings exceedingly difficult. "

This vampire, has suffered a Vissicitude modification (he has decreased almost 20cm, so he's no longer a big guy of 210cm). Other player has a really high level of Temporis, and he was wondering if using the level 6 "Laquesis Kiss" (or "Kiss of Laquesis", I don't really know because I have the spanish version of Vampire: Dark Ages 20th Aniversary Edition), he can "rewind" the changes made by Vissicitude, according to it's Flaw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unlikely that violence counts as “damage and wear due to time”.

> ### V20, page 469
>
> This power does not reverse history in any way; it merely reverses or accelerates the effects of time in terms of wear and tear. Moreover, a target cannot regress to an earlier or incomplete state of being. … For the undead and other corpses, it is the moment of death. … **Also, this power only accounts for damage and wear due to time.** A child amputee reverted to a baby will not regenerate her missing arm, nor will a broken sword become anything but newly crafted shards.

Comment: Thank you, I've not commented before just because I had no time. Quite a good answer!